# PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp doesn't work with Items in the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

iI'm working on a program which should change the checkbox state by clicking on it.

I used a "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Event. The Problem is that, it doesn't get called when i press on an item. It only get called if i click on an empty place in the Datagrid.

Code:

```
    Private Sub BefundePat1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles BefundePat1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp

    Dim cell As DataGridCell = getGridCell(e.OriginalSource)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        If BefundePat1.Columns(BefundePat1.Columns.Count - 1) Is cell.Column Then
            If TypeOf cell.DataContext Is DataRowView Then
                Dim dr As DataRowView = cell.DataContext
                If dr.Row.Item("NR_TAKE") = True Then
                    dr.Row.Item("NR_TAKE") = False
                Else
                    dr.Row.Item("NR_TAKE") = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Is it possible that it get distracted by the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event i also have in the programm?

Kind Regards

Comment: It doesn't get called when you click on what item? Also, a CheckBox is checked/unchecked when you click on it by default so what issue are you trying to solve here?

Comment: If in the datagrid are some items of a datatable. If this itemsource is nothing the event will get called otherwise not.

Comment: Is "BefundePat1" the DataGrid?

Comment: Yes this is the DataGrid.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes i've tried it. But it didn't work. I now call the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp while the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event is running. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but tou could try to define a `CellStyle` that raises the event for each `DataGridCell`. Remove `Handles BefundePat1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` from your event handler and add the style in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BefundePat1" ...>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="BefundePat1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

If this doesn't work, you could try handling the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. Please clarify your requirements if you need any further help.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. I now call the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp while the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event is running. Thank you for your help.